# IS Insert Select FROM CTP an atomic transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, transactions

Can someone please tell me if insert select from CTE is still an atomic transaction?

Here is my example:

```
WITH SELECTION AS (
     SELECT [Code], [Field1], [Field2] 
     FROM [Products] 
     WHERE [Active] = 1 AND Code NOT IN (SELECT [Code] FROM [SomeOtherTable])
)
INSERT INTO JobQueue ([Field1], [Field2], [Code]) 
   SELECT Field1, Field2, Code 
   FROM SELECTION
```

Please, do not pay attention on T-SQL logic as it is not an exact example of what I am doing.

Comment: Hello, I believe this thread would help you with the question fi I have understood you correctly. https://stackoverflow.com/q/1071286/12660350

Answer (score 0):

Of course. There is no exception of transactional behaviour in one single DML query. A single Query is a query beginning by SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, MERGE, TRUNCATE, or WITH...