# How to know the lock status for a row, without updating the record

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, transactions, locking

I am using the readcommited isolation level to update a row in one transaction. From other transaction, How should I find there is a lock placed on the same row without trying to update the row.
Any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check which locks are held on a table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/694581/how-to-check-which-locks-are-held-on-a-table)

Comment: This thread http://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?t=14418 shows, inquiring a row level lock will be very tedious

Answer (score 2):

The only way to check for a lock is by obtaining the lock your self. This is not specific to databases, is a general issue with concurrency. Any form of API that 'checks' if a lock is held or not is fundamentally broken because by definition any action performed based on the result of this API check is *wrong*, as is base don stale, obsolete information. Knowing that lock *was not held when the API checked for it* does not mean is not held by the time the API returned.

**You cannot possibly write a correct program if you *inquire* about locks. the only way to write a correct program is to *acquire* locks. True in SQL as in any other programming language.**

Nothing stops you from attempting to acquire a lock with instant timeout ([`SET LOCK_TIMEOUT 0`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189470.aspx)) and handle the lock timeout error that occurs on conflict.

Comment: Thanks for the design information. Can you please detail or explain some ways about acquiring locks.

Comment: use [lock hints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx). Explain your scenario and maybe we can give more details how to do it.

Comment: As a side comment: inquiring for a row lock using the DMVs is basically impossible because you must know exactly the locking protocol and the physical structure of the database. Case in point: checking to see if row with key 'foo' is locked or no by looking up the key lock resource (and good luck compiling *that*) is not enough. A concurent transaction may had used page granularity and only locked the *page* containing the row. You cannot win this.

Comment: I have a view screen and update screen. The first operation in the update screen is a select operation to display the data for editing, which must be blocked for the concurrent transaction. but View screen 'select' must be allowed.

Comment: You cannot hold locks for as long as user edit screen anyway. Use [optimistic concurrency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control) instead. At worst, use explicit [app locks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx). Absolutely do not use data locks for 'edit' screens.

Answer (score 1):

To get the information about lock, you can execute  `sp_lock` procedure.

NOTE:  `VIEW SERVER STATE` permission is required.

In SQL Server 2008, you can use [sys.dm_tran_locks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190345.aspx) dynamic management view.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can find the lock on table level not on row level

try below code it will give the table which is currently lock.

```
SELECT t.name as [Table Name]
FROM sys.dm_tran_locks as t1
Join sys.objects o1 on o1.object_id = t1.resource_associated_entity_id
Join sys.tables t on o1.object_id = t.object_id
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Row level lock could not be obtained it seems. Ref http://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?t=14418