# Query to get historical queries that ran and caused transactional locks

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there a way, or a stored procedure or query that I can run, to get a list of all the queries/transactions that previously ran on the database and are locking tables.

I am looking into doing an analysis to see which transactions are locking what tables.

Comment: All queries are locking tables to various degrees at all times, but it's not a problem unless it is impacting performance or causing deadlocks. Do you have a performance or deadlock issue that you're trying to solve?

Comment: If you need that kind of data, you'll have to gather it yourself (or use a 3rd party tool)

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Yes that is exactly what I am looking for. Any idea how I can do that.

Comment: Your question remains far too general to pose a specific answer. Why don't you start here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/694581/how-to-check-which-locks-are-held-on-a-table

Answer (score 0):

It's a more tricky question that it seems.

Historical data regarding locking, as long as we aren't talking about something like "query store" or some other technology that can be thought of as "external", is accumulated by DMV [sys.dm_db_index_operational_stats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-index-operational-stats-transact-sql).

This DMV is relatively stable. But its counterpart [sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-procedure-stats-transact-sql) has a propensity to change as soon as particular plan, which could accumulate some "interesting" data, is recompiled.

This transient property of accumulated data tends to be more pronounced as the rate of change of statistics gets higher. So, you can see that sometimes (or even most of the times) you might not get an exact link between a lock and its cause using DMV from **stats family, but knowing how the omission occurs, you have some information to make good judgment.

Add [sys.sql_dependencies](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174402(v=sql.110).aspx) linking lock impacted objects and procedures, and it is a starting point.

Please note additional resources for ***stats DMV family:

- [Execution Related Dynamic Management Views and Functions (Transact-SQL)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188068(v=sql.110).aspx)
- [sys.dm_exec_query_stats](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189741(v=sql.110).aspx)
- [sys.dm_exec_trigger_stats](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280646(v=sql.110).aspx)