# How to know what is the wait time for a lock on particular table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure dbo.testproc1 that acquires an exclusive table lock on a table dbo.L.
This database is used in a multi-user environment and now how can I find, how much time is spent on waiting for this exclusive lock (by other concurrent sessions)?

I know sys.dm_os_wait_stats can be used to find the wait times, but how can I drill down to a specific lock on a particular table?

Comment: You want to find overall statistics? Or just for a particular currently waiting query

Comment: @charlieface : Not for currently waiting query. Need to find amount of time that was already spent by other sessions waiting for this lock.

Comment: You cannot easily connect specific lock from session to another session without "Extended Events". You can connect two session and add attributes (actual table lock) by connection of tables: sys.dm_exec_requests (for blocking session id), sys.dm_tran_locks (for associated_entity, request_session_id and lock detail) and derive your time as diff between session and lock start time. Something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/694581/how-to-check-which-locks-are-held-on-a-table ?